# PostgreSQL Using Max and Round

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, rounding

How do you use MAX and ROUND at the same time?

i.e.

SELECT
customer_id,
MAX(some_number)
FROM
customer_data
GROUP BY
customer_id;

60.2354125

Would like to return the result of 60.24

Answer (score 2):

You would write this as:

```
SELECT customer_id, ROUND(MAX(some_number), 2)
FROM customer_data
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you can convert to a numeric first:

```
SELECT customer_id, ROUND(MAX(some_number)::numeric, 2)
FROM customer_data
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: I think I'm not able to get this to work because of the data type?  I get the following error message: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Gordon.  The solution was casting as numeric

```
round(MAX(cast(some_number as numeric)),2)
```